# How to login to a website in uwp windows 10 and stay logged in?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am building a UWP app for windows 10. I want the users to be able to login to a website and retrieve data from that site using the login information provided. How to login to a website programmatically and save the login credentials and login automatically the next time the user opens the app ? I want the login information to be available throughout the app so that in all the pag

Comment: Any attempt so far to implement this? Any specific problem you are having?

Comment: Did you try saving the login information in the app data?

Comment: No. I don't know where to start. I looked up the html and it has some hidden fields. I am a beginner and I don't know how to store the data returned by the server in the app data if the login works.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on the web app you're trying to connect to. Actually, you don't connect to the web app or to a site but most likely to some backend services which back up the whole web application. The UI is called in this case a web client. What you are trying to do, is to create a desktop client (the UWP app).

Unless this site you're speaking of, has no clear documentation of how to use a certain API to connect to it, I don't see a way you can achieve this.

Additionaly, I am sure this whole approach will raise suspicions when your app might be eventually under certification, before being published in the Windows Store. If it doesn't pass the certification, only you can use it, others can't, 'cause it won't be available for them.

Comment: assuming that i get reply from the server and the login is successful, how to store the user data and use the same again when the user opens the app again

Answer (score 0):

if you have the login information. I guess you have a token to make a valid requests.

Just need to save this information in the storage of your application and get the saved data when it will be necessary.

Please check this example how to use Storage in UWP apps
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185401.aspx

I recommend you to use Json format to save the data in your storage with this technique you can serialize a your data very easy.

here is an example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C

I always use this approach in my apps and they work very well.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have done a project similar to your project. My project involved logging in onto a website inside an UWP-application. I wanted to inject login-information into the DOM without the user knowing the information.

Quickly I concluded that the WebView Class is too limited and tightly protected to get it working. I resorted to an alternative webbrowser for UWP-applications named Gecko. Gecko is a .NET implementation of Firefox, found a tutorial on how to get it working and it worked right out of the box.

In the case of your project you have three options:

1. Use a UWP popup (MenuFlyOut class) where the user inserts their data. You then inject the inserted data into the DOM of the browser.
2. Let the user insert their credentials inside the DOM and intercept the keystrokes.
3. Let the user insert their credentials inside the DOM and retrieve the information by requesting the value of the inputs inside the DOM.

To use the values everywhere throughout the application you can create a static attribute inside the App-class inside the App.Xaml.cs file.

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    internal static String Username { get; set; }
    internal static String Password { get; set; }
    public App()
    {
```

If you want to use the variables again you can use them like this:

```
App.Username
```